# Reactivate Yammer user via API and PowerShell

Tags: yammer

I am trying to workout if it's possible to reactivate a suspended user in Yammer, through the API in PowerShell?

From what I understand, there is no supported endpoint in Yammer for reactivating users, but in the Network Admin UI there is a "Reactivate User" button next to suspended user accounts in the 'Remove Users' section, so there is obviously a way to do this "behind the scenes".

I used Fiddler, to trace the request when clicking the 'Reactivate User' button in the UI, which gave me the URL and content type in the code below.

Edit: I should also add, that the code below is not reactivating the user, but I am getting an 'OK' response and '200' status from the webRequest when executing.

Here is a cut down version of the code I am using:

```
$reactUserId = read-host -Prompt "Enter user ID"
$headers = Get-BearerToken
$urlToCall = "https://www.yammer.com/companyname.com/admin/reactivate_user?user_id=$($reactUserId)"

$webRequest = Invoke-WebRequest $urlToCall -Method POST -Headers $headers -ContentType "text/html; charset=utf-8"
```